# split one array into two parts which maximize the sum of product of element of each part

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I want to partition one array into 2 part. if the products of elements of each part equals to p1 , p2. our goal is to p1+p2 is maximize. can you sole it in polynomial complexity?
thanks

Comment: What are the restrictions? Can there be negative elements?

Comment: you do not know anything about the order of the elements. Hence the first step we can take is to aort the elements. This can be done in polynomial time

Comment: no there is not negative or zero elements

Comment: It can't be solve with dynamic programming because you can't dice the problem to sub problems and build solution from them.

Answer (score 0):

As there are no negative elements, simply do this:

```
foreach element in array
    if element < 1
         add to list1
    else
         add to list2
```

Maximizes the sum of products and runs in linear time. Then:

```
product1 = 1
foreach element in list1
    product1 = product1 * element
```

Etc. Note that this will result in the empty set having a product of 1 - this is correct.

Comment: The "no-negative" assumption is not strong enough to make this algorithm correct. For example: [1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2] should be splitted evenly: [1/2,1/2],[1/2,1/2] - while the algorithm will yield a wrong answer.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly? Do the two lists each need to be half the original list? Because if not, [1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2] should be split into [1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2], [] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product). [1/2,1/2],[1/2,1/2] would be the worst possible solution.

Comment: And if each list has to have *at least one* element, that is again easy to solve - after doing the above, if one list is empty, move the maximum element to the other list if the product is < 1, or the minimum element if the product is >= 1, this is again linear.